# Marginnote eats first item in thmtool's mdframed

Tags: lists, mdframed, thmtools

In short, when I create a `\marginnote` and a list inside of a `thmtools` box which uses `mdframed`, the list formatting of the first item in the list gets eaten.

[Here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/nshwhrhssrvc)'s a minimal working example.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,mdframed}
\declaretheorem[mdframed={},name=Boxed]{theoremboxed}
\declaretheorem[name=Unboxed]{theoremunboxed}

\begin{document}

\begin{theoremboxed} \marginnote{Note}
    Here is a list.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item 1.
        \item Item 2.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theoremboxed}

\begin{theoremunboxed} \marginnote{Note}
    Here is a list.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item 1.
        \item Item 2.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theoremunboxed}

\begin{mdframed} \marginnote{Note}
    Here is a list.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item 1.
        \item Item 2.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Here is what it looks like when compiled:[image: Compiled PDF]

The only box with the issue is the first one. Namely, the problem is that the label of the first item has disappeared and moved to the second item.

Comment: It works fine using  `Here is a list. \marginnote{Note}`

Comment: Didn't dig into, but `\begin{theoremboxed} \leavevmode\marginnote{Note} ...` seems to work.